# Getting the value and text from a datalist in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-datalist

I am trying to get the value in the #place input and keep it in that input but have the fax number go into the #fax input?  Is it possible to get both values and drop them into the respective locations.

```
input type="text" id="place" list="places">
<datalist id="places">
    <option value="WVC">503-882-1212</option>
    <option value="HAM">612-883-1414</option>
    <option value="WON">317-445-8585</option>
</datalist>
<br>
<input type="text" id="fax">
```

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery attr value

```js
     $(document).on('change', '#place', function () {
         $("#fax").val($("#places option[value='" + $("#place").val() + "']").attr("label"));
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="place" list="places">
    <datalist id="places">
        <option value="WVC" label="503-882-1212"></option>
        <option value="HAM" label="612-883-1414"></option>
        <option value="WON" label="317-445-8585"></option>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="fax">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to achieve this effect given the starting code you gave us. First, you need to capture any change to your input element by adding an event listener.

Second, using javascript you just need to select the correct option element from all of the ones present, and extract the fax number, which is the tags innerHTML.

```
<input type="text" id="place" list="places">
<datalist id="places">
    <option value="WVC">503-882-1212</option>
    <option value="HAM">612-883-1414</option>
    <option value="WON">317-445-8585</option>
</datalist>
<br>
<input type="text" id="fax">
<script>
    document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
        var val = document.querySelector('input').value;
        faxNum = document.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + val + '"]')[0].innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('#fax').value = faxNum;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but I have more than one input, like 10, how do I make it more precise?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you would go about doing that, I would check the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) documentation and see which options you can implement. Unless you have fax number labels with the same value, there shouldn't be any need to make it more precise.