# Remove an ID if a input value is = some defined code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove an input id when another input id having value in defined values

my codes

```
setInterval(function() {
  var MaterialGod = [
    "FPPUTHP1100000",
    "FPPUTHP1100000",
    "FPPUTHP1110000",
    "FPPUTHP1500000",
    "FPPUTHP1680000",
    "FPPUTHP1690000",
    "FPPUTHP1590000"
  ];

  $.each(MaterialGod, function(index) {
    if ($("label:contains('Meterial Code')").parent().next().find('input').val() == index) {
      $('#__item5-__box2-0').remove();
    }
  })
}, 100);
```

Pls give your advise what i m doing wrong

Comment: `index` is the array index, not the value of the array element.

Comment: The second argument to the callback function is the element.

Comment: @Barmar Dear Sir i am a newbie pls correct my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the array index, not the array element, with the value.

There's also no reason to put the selector in the loop, since you're selecting the same input every time.

Just get the input value, and use `.includes()` to see if it's in the array.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var MaterialGod = [
    "FPPUTHP1100000",
    "FPPUTHP1100000",
    "FPPUTHP1110000",
    "FPPUTHP1500000",
    "FPPUTHP1680000",
    "FPPUTHP1690000",
    "FPPUTHP1590000"
  ];
  if MaterialGod.includes($("label:contains('Meterial Code')").parent().next().find('input').val()) {
    $('#__item5-__box2-0').remove();
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Its Worked Fine... Thanks :) I am a new user so cant vote UP

Comment: @SachinAgarwal You've changed the question completely. If you have a different problem, post a new question.

Comment: @Barmar I m a new user stackoverflow banned me for asking new question....it was very urgent

Comment: `$(this).find("option:selected").text()` contains the text of the selected option. You can show that in the other place.

Comment: @Barmar its not working.. may be i am doing something wrong.. can you post the whole code here?

Comment: `$("#KASHIPUR")
.append(HTMLOptions).on("change", function() {
 
 $("label:contains('Driver Mobile No')").parent().next().find('input').val(this.value); $("#otherInput").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());

})
    .trigger("change");
});`

Comment: @Barmar Dear Sir, It is still not working... May be because `$("#KASHIPUR")` is a `Datalist` Id not a `Select` Id

Comment: `$("#KASHIPUR") .append(HTMLOptions)` This is working very fine and i want to trigger the second element `$("label:contains('Driver Mobile No')").parent().next().find('input')` here

Comment: This is why we need a real question, with the HTML showing so I can see what the relevant elements are.

Comment: @Barmar Dear Sir finally did with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086427/setting-hidden-datalist-option-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173544/getting-the-value-and-text-from-a-datalist-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong you are comparing with index instead of value. Try comparing with value as shown in below code.

```
  setInterval(function() {
      var MaterialGod = [
        "FPPUTHP1100000",
        "FPPUTHP1100000",
        "FPPUTHP1110000",
        "FPPUTHP1500000",
        "FPPUTHP1680000",
        "FPPUTHP1690000",
        "FPPUTHP1590000"
      ];
    
      $.each(MaterialGod, function(index,iVal) {
        if ($("label:contains('Meterial Code')").parent().next().find('input').val() == iVal) {
          $('#__item5-__box2-0').remove();
        }
      })
    }, 100);
```