# HTML Dropdown Box with Search and Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdownbox

I've tried to search for what I'm after, and this is the closest I can get:

**Make a Dropdown with Search Box using jQuery** (by Yogesh Singh)
https://makitweb.com/make-a-dropdown-with-search-box-using-jquery/

- It can provide a HTML Dropdown with Search capability.
- However, what I hope to have is to have input capability as well. I.e., if nothing found, then use the user input as the result.

I tried to look at the code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  // Initialize select2
  $("#selUser").select2();

  // Read selected option
  $('#but_read').click(function(){
    var username = $('#selUser option:selected').text();
    var userid = $('#selUser').val();

    $('#result').html("id : " + userid + ", name : " + username);

  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** using `datalist`. Requirement:

- if found, use found value as the result.
- if nothing found, then use the user input as the result.

Maybe both are the same case, but I don't know js well to say that.

```js
     $(document).on('change', '#place', function () {
         $("#fax").val($("#place").val());
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="place" list="places">
    <datalist id="places">
        <option value="WVC" label="503-882-1212"></option>
        <option value="HAM" label="612-883-1414"></option>
        <option value="WON" label="317-445-8585"></option>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="fax">
```

I don't see an easy way to do that myself, as I don't know js quite well.
It is possible, to use the user input as the result if nothing found? thx

Comment: You could use the standard `datalist` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Wow, as simple as THAT!! Thanks! Update, So @RoryMcCrossan, would you answer with a js script showing the final selection/input result please?

Comment: I then searched and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173544/, but it can only do selection, but not input.

Comment: Can you specify the expected result?

Comment: Please show html code too.

Comment: Given your update, use the same field to read the value. You're overcomplicating it by having two fields. If you do it in a single field you don't need JS at all as the control works exactly as you require

Comment: Approach you need to take will depend on what you intend to do with the user entry. Are you planning to search for the value in your database? In that case you will not find anything against a new value entered. I have had a similar case where when user enters a new value, then first that value is added into a table and then use the generated ID into doing next operation. Could you explain your requirement in more details please?

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner, think of google search, does that match what I described, _basically_, simplified 1000 times?

Comment: Where do you plan to get the list from?

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner, I'm preparing my list from my Go back end.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it serves your purpose

Comment: I'm not accusing you of anything. I was trying to help you. Also I'm not available at all times just to answer your questions. I happened to be passing this one and presumed that you'd manage to figure out how to use a basic control by yourself. Clearly not.

Comment: _"I happened to be passing this one"_, then why don't you just leave me alone? _"I'm not available at all times just to answer your questions"_ then why came back spending your precious time and accuse people? Let me stress again, the code that you blamed, is the answer from another question. Leave me and that answer alone, let me _" figure out how to use a basic control "_ myself, I don't need your help, and I got what I want without your gracious humongous help. You call it _"trying to help"_ but apparently I have a totally different view to your behavior and attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<datalist>` is like a separate `select` element and linked to the text field previous to it and simply updates the value of textfield based on what is selected. If you like to run your code based on change event on the text field, you need to read the `datalist` first and then pick the label from it. If there is no value, then pick the text from the textfield.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change', '#place', function () {
        let myString = 
               $(this).next().find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("label");
        myString = myString ? myString : $(this).val();
        $("#fax").val(myString);
        $(this).val(myString); //IF YOU LIKE TO SHOW SAME STRING IN TEXT FIELD TOO
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="place" list="places">
    <datalist id="places">
        <option value="WVC" label="503-882-1212"></option>
        <option value="HAM" label="612-883-1414"></option>
        <option value="WON" label="317-445-8585"></option>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="fax">
```